# Finding A,B and A intersection B of 2 sets in linear time without a hashtable

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, set, hashtable

*Given two sets A and B, how can I find the elements that are present only in A, present in both A and B, and present only in B, in linear time, and without using a hashtable.*

Someone told of me doing something as follows,
For each element in set B, try adding it to set A. If you're able to add it, it means the element is not present in set A, so, add it to the list of **elements exclusive to set B**. However, If you're not able to add it, it means, such an element already exists in set A, and so, add it to the list of **elements that are common to both set A and set B**.

However, with this approach, how can I find **elements that are present only in set A**?

PS : I was asked this question at an interview, and I gave him multiple solutions such as follows. However, the interviewer wanted the solution above.

1. Using a O(n^2) loop pair
2. Using a hashtable in O(n)
3. Sorting the sets in O(n.logn) and comparing between the elements in both sets, and incrementing based on values.

Comment: "try adding it to set A" is O(n) unless the set is a hashtable or another structure with efficient lookup; therefore trying to add all elements of B to A is O(n2).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Yes, the set has to be implemented with hashing or something equivalent in order to make adding elements O(1). I guess that's ok, it is just not allowed to use an additional hashmap.

Comment: if the sets are hashtables, you just use `contains` and don't try to actually add elements. It's very simple then.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, As mentioned in title, I'm looking for a solution without hashtable.

Comment: No, the assignment says "given two sets...". You can't be "given a set" if it's not some specific data structure. So, what is it? An array? A linked list? A hashtable?

Answer (score 0):

Just run the same procedure again with A and B interchanged. This is still O(n).

Comment: I didn't quite get that. But the first time you do, A's contents have already changed. So, it will affect the second time you do upon interchanging

Comment: @saltandwater: You don'r really have to modify the sets to perform the algorithm. Alternatively you could create copies of the sets.

Comment: Is there a way to only check if adding an element to a set is possible, without actually adding it. I was thinking checking the return value of setA.add(element from setB), in which case, the element would get added to setA. How can I achieve this, as you mentioned, without actually adding the element to setA, and modifying the set?

Comment: @saltandwater: Sure, as Marko Topolnik already mentioned in one of the comments, `HashSet` has the method `contains` which does exactly this, well, to be precise, the opposite of it,

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a bit cheating because if Sets are hash-tables, then you are allowed hash-tables...
e.g.
 1. create a set T
 2. add All elements in A to T,
 3. add all elements in B to T, ( you know which common and which are not)
 4. clear T
 5. add all elements in B to T,
 6. add all elements in A to T...

Answer (score 0):

You were actually surprisingly close with your first guess.

To find all of the elements in set `bar` that aren't in `foo`, you need to check if any of them are contained.

```
for(int i : bar) {
    if (!foo.contains(i)) {
        barLessFoo.add(i);
    }
}
```

To find all of the elements in `foo` that aren't in `bar`, you need to reverse the operation.

```
for(int i : foo) {
    if(!bar.contains(i)) {
        fooLessBar.add(i);
    }
}
```

No loop pairs are needed for this; you're only iterating each collection once.

This is still O(n), although the argument can be made, depending on the data structure backing `foo` and `bar`, it can be O(n<sup>2</sup>), since only `Set`s guarantee O(1) lookup time on `contains`.